# Como colocar uma imagem de background e deixa-la responsiva?

Tags: c#, winforms

Estou aprendendo C#, então gostaria de saber como pôr uma imagem de fundo (*background*) e também retirar as bordas azuis. Estou usando o Visual Studio.

**Ps**: alguns vídeos que vi no YouTube se resumiam a basicamente ir nas propriedades do `form` e definir no `Appearance` uma imagem, mas esta técnica não altera o código do formulário e deixa bordas diferentes do método que vi com `buttons` onde se ia no código direto e alterava a sua aparência sem deixar bordas

Estou utilizando Windows Forms.

Comment: Isso em Windows Forms?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use o [`BackgroundImageLayout`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.backgroundimagelayout.aspx) dessa forma:

```
SeuObjeto.BackgroundImageLayout = ImageLayout.Stretch;
```

Você também pode usar o `Zoom`, se preferir.

Verifique mais detalhes no [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.imagelayout.aspx).